# Set start position for WPF Datagrid

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I want to freeze first 2 columns in my WPF Datagrid which I managed to do using FrozenColumnCount property. However when I ran the program I see that the horizontal scroll bar starts after frozen columns which looks wierd. Is there a way to start my Horizontal scrollbar from first column using some styles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to edit the control template, in template you can set the starting column for PART_HorizontalScrollBar and achieve result you want.

```
<ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" Grid.Column="1" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Orientation="Horizontal" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"/>
```